# OS X shows a MAC address different from my router’s

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, mac-address

My router’s hardware MAC address (as indicated on the label on the back) is different from the MAC address I noticed on my MacBook. I had a look at the IPv6 settings and it shows a different router MAC address:

[image]

Does this mean my computer has been hacked into or someone has cloned my MacBook remotely?

Comment: I know for a fact your MacBook has not been cloned remotely.

Comment: Your router will likely have a MAC address for each network (WAN, LAN, Wi-Fi, etc.) to which it connects. A MAC address is only relevant on the layer-2 network where it exists.

Comment: What are you even talking about? What “router hardware MAC address”? And where did you “notice” a MAC address on your MacBook?

Comment: I checked in systems preferences, network, advanced, Wifi, TCPIP, IPV6, router, and router Mac address.I looked at the back of my router and the Mac address at the back of my router hardware does not match what is on the wifi...as mentioned above.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thank you Ramhound for the re-assurance, could you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Your router has at least three network interfaces: WAN, LAN and WiFi. Every interface has its own MAC address. Also, there’s no MAC address at that location in OS X. Please provide a screenshot of what exactly you’re talking about.

Comment: The section i am talking about is the field where it shows the detailed information of the router - IPV6 address, in this field I can see my Macbook mac address and another mac address I do not recognise if that helps.

Comment: @Williams If you feel that one of the answers was sufficient, please accept it. Or do you require additional information?

Answer (score 1):

There is no MAC address at all on the screenshot. You’re confused by IPv6 addresses because they also use a colon to separate groups.

That being said, as I already mention in my comment: A wireless router has multiple network interfaces. It has at least one WiFi interface and at least one wired interface. Most consumer routers have two wired interfaces. Each interface has its own MAC address. If your router’s label has only one MAC address, that’s insufficient.

There is no evidence whatsoever that your security has been compromised. There’s also no such thing as hackers “remotely cloning a PC”.

If you actually have a IPv6 router, it looks like this (still no MAC addresses):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Daniel B, I feel a lot better and relaxed now with the information you have given me.

Answer (score 0):

MAC addresses are a property of a network interface.  Each network interface will have its own.

So your Macintosh system's Ethernet port has it's own MAC address, and your router's Ethernet port will have a second, separate MAC address.

I think you can open a terminal and enter the command `arp -a` or `arp`.  This will tell you all the MAC addresses your system has seen and the associated IP address.  Your router's IP should be among those and it should correspond with the router's MAC.

Your screen shot shows IP version 6 addresses.  These are not MAC addresses.

Comment: Hi LawrenceC, Thanks for the feedback much appreciated.